How to add version data to github-webhook payload
Added github-webhook payload as a parameter to the jenkins pipeline script.
The purpose is to take the version data from the github-webhook payload and use it as a tag when building docker images.
But I don't know how to add version data from github-webhook payload.
I thought the best way was to use github's tag function, but I couldn't get it for the tag because that pipeline only works at pull request.
I thought I could get it through a branch name or a commit message, but I don't know if this is okay.
What are some good ways to add version data to the github-webhook payload?
This is my jenkins pipeline script and it call upon pull request.
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def version = null

pipeline {
  agent any

  parameters { string(name: 'payload', defaultValue: '', description: 'github api payload') }

  stages {
    stage('Get Version') {
        steps {
          script {
                def myobj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(payload)
          
                version = myobj.???
          
          }
        }
    } 

    stage('Build') {
      steps {
          sh '''
          bash $HOME/my_pipeline/docker/image.sh \
          --build="APP_ENV=stag" \
          -- web ${version} 192.168.1.10:5000
          '''
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          bash $HOME/my_pipeline/docker/update.sh \
          --context=stag \
          --stack=ancean\
          -- web ${version} 192.168.1.10:5000
        '''
      }
    }
  }
}

Part of the payload data. Unnecessary url data has been removed.
    {
    "action": "closed",
    "number": 3,
    "pull_request": {
    "id": ...,
    "node_id": "...",
    "number": 3,
    "state": "closed",
    "locked": false,
    "title": "branch tag test",
    "user": {
      "login": "Antoliny0919",
      "id": ...,
      "node_id": "...",
     
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Antoliny0919",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "body": null,
    "created_at": "2024-07-29T10:17:54Z",
    "updated_at": "2024-07-29T10:18:28Z",
    "closed_at": "2024-07-29T10:18:28Z",
    "merged_at": "2024-07-29T10:18:28Z",
    "merge_commit_sha": "...",
    "assignee": null,
    "assignees": [

    ],
    "requested_reviewers": [

    ],
    "requested_teams": [

    ],
    "labels": [

    ],
    "milestone": null,
    "draft": false,
    "head": {
      "label": "Antoliny0919:hotfix",
      "ref": "hotfix",
      "sha": "...",
      "user": {
        "login": "Antoliny0919",
        "id": ...,
        "node_id": "...",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
      },
      "repo": {
        "id": ...,
        "node_id": "...",
        "name": "web-hook-test",
        "full_name": "Antoliny0919/web-hook-test",
        "private": false,
        "owner": {
          "login": "Antoliny0919",
          "id": ...,
          "node_id": "...",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
        },
        "description": null,
        "fork": false,
        "created_at": "2024-07-28T22:47:07Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-07-29T10:02:23Z",
        "pushed_at": "2024-07-29T10:17:54Z",
        "homepage": null,
        "size": 5,
        "stargazers_count": 0,
        "watchers_count": 0,
        "language": null,
        "has_issues": true,
        "has_projects": true,
        "has_downloads": true,
        "has_wiki": false,
        "has_pages": false,
        "has_discussions": false,
        "forks_count": 0,
        "mirror_url": null,
        "archived": false,
        "disabled": false,
        "open_issues_count": 0,
        "license": null,
        "allow_forking": true,
        "is_template": false,
        "web_commit_signoff_required": false,
        "topics": [

        ],
        "visibility": "public",
        "forks": 0,
        "open_issues": 0,
        "watchers": 0,
        "default_branch": "main",
        "allow_squash_merge": true,
        "allow_merge_commit": true,
        "allow_rebase_merge": true,
        "allow_auto_merge": false,
        "delete_branch_on_merge": false,
        "allow_update_branch": false,
        "use_squash_pr_title_as_default": false,
        "squash_merge_commit_message": "COMMIT_MESSAGES",
        "squash_merge_commit_title": "COMMIT_OR_PR_TITLE",
        "merge_commit_message": "PR_TITLE",
        "merge_commit_title": "MERGE_MESSAGE"
      }
    },
    ...



I tried pull request by adding tag to commit.


It's unclear what you mean by version data. Can you attach an example payload and point out the field you'd like to reference?

Version data to be used to tag a docker image. like v1.0.0, v1.0.1, I will attach the payload data to the body of the HTTP POST Request delivered when performing the pull request of the github-webhook.

Can you attach an example payload is done, now please could you point out the field you'd like to reference?
